# Pandas rolling window: как использовать min_periods для конца списка?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как применить `min_periods` к концу списка.

Пример:

```
s = pd.series(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

Результат `s.rolling(4, min_periods=1)` будет:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
...
7 8 9 10
```

Но хотелось бы получить:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
...
7 8 9 10
8 9 10
9 10
10
```

Порядок значений важен.

Есть ли возможность получить такой результат используя функцию `rolling`?
Или же имеется иная функция с таким функционалом?

Comment: Не понятно как получилось на ру..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно применить плавающее окно к перевернутой (задом-наперёд) последовательности, применить нужную нам функцию к перевернутому окну и опять же перевернуть результат.

Пример (для примера использовал кастомную функцию суммирования с выводом отладочной информации):

```
def my_sum(ser):
     print(ser.to_list())
     return ser.sum()
```

---

```
In [92]: s[::-1].rolling(4, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: my_sum(x[::-1]), raw=False)[::-1]
[10.0]
[9.0, 10.0]
[8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
[7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
[6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Out[92]:
0    10.0
1    14.0
2    18.0
3    22.0
4    26.0
5    30.0
6    34.0
7    27.0
8    19.0
9    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Так он меняет местами значения. Получаем в начале 10, 10 9.. Но это не тоже самое что 9 10, 10 в конце. Порядок значений важен.

Comment: @Denis, какую функцию вы хотите применить к плавающему окну?

Comment: Кастомную, мне важно что бы когда я дохожу до конца списка, окно динамически уменьшалось, и как я уже сказал, порядок значений важен.

Comment: @Denis, исправил ответ - смотрите вывод отладочной информации - порядок значений сохранен...

Comment: Хм, выглядит так, что при помощи трансформация передоваемых значений и перевернутого списка, результат тот что надо. Спасибо.